# Modify function using (this) and next() so can be used with many sets of elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

The function below dynamically adds content to a multi-select element using the [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) (in this example text is input into #newItem and added to #example1, and is based on this ['Refresh' demo](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh).

I'm using this on 100+ elements and would therefore like to modify the function so that the selectors don't need to be specified for each element. I've used both `(this)` and `next()` in the past, but this function is a little more sophisticated than what I've worked with previously and I don't know how to modify it in order to use the same selectors for the entire form.

I've posted a working example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/ezxSF/24/

*JS*

```
$(function () {
    var el = $("#example1").multiselect(),
    selected = $('#selected'),
    newItem = $('#newItem');
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var v = newItem.val(), opt = $('<option />', {
            value: v,
            text: v
        });
        if (selected.is(':checked')) {
            opt.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        opt.appendTo(el);
        el.multiselect('refresh');
    });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="newItem" />
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />    
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="selected" />Selected?</label>
    <select id="example1" name="example-refresh" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this one:

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
```

to a class, so we have a common starting point

```
<input type="button" class="add" value="Add" />
```

Then do :

```
$(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
      var el       = $(this).siblings('select').multiselect(),
          selected = $(this).siblings('label').find('input[type="checkbox"]'),
          newItem  = $(this).prev('input'),
          v        = newItem.val(), 
          opt      = $('<option />', { value: v, text : v });

      if (selected.is(':checked')) {
          opt.prop('selected', true);
      }
      opt.appendTo(el);
      el.multiselect('refresh');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just needed to call the multiselect widget by class separately and then it worked like a dream :-) One question - since these won't be the only 2 siblings in the <div> or <table>, is there another way that I can call them? There are 3 - 4 elements per row, and if possible I'd like to have the text boxes on the following row.

Comment: @ChayaCooper - Not sure I get it, `siblings('select')` only gets siblings that are select tags, like `<select>`, and there's only one of those? You can always use classes when targeting stuff like this.

Comment: My mistake - I thought it was referring to other elements at the same level :-) So how do I specify which input elements are paired together (so that the text box updates the correct <select> element)?

Comment: Not sure I get the question. If the markup is like it is in the question, contained in container div elements, there's no problem, otherwise you will have to wrap it in container elements. Check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tRfv4/) for an example.

Comment: Since most of my elements are in tables, I need to modify the function a bit so that each set doesn't need to be wrapped in it's own container element. I'd like to use the method shown here (which requires my setting the name of the 2nd element to match the id of the 1rst element selected), but I'm not sure how to integrate it into this function http://stackoverflow.com/a/15654878/1056713